# How do I determine the build version of McAfee Agent 4.5 from the commandline (Linux)?

Tags: linux, mcafee

It looks like the cma process(es) on my RHEL 5.6 box leak memory.

I see that in [4.5.0 patch 1](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=PD22625) fixes for a couple memory leaks were provided.

But I can't tell which version our IaaS provider is running. I can see a 4.5.0 directory in the McAfee directory but I've tried running `strings` on binaries to no avail.

McAfee KB link [here](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB68472) re: build numbers for non-Windows.

Anyone know how I can tell which build is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the naming of the RPM itself. i.e.:

```
[root@server ~]# rpm -q MFEcma
MFEcma-4.5.0-1470
```

1470 equates to patch 1 as listed in the aforementioned KB [link](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB68472).

Doesn't explain my alleged memory leak but it wouldn't surprise me if patch 3 fixes an undocumented leak...